# Stay awake while charging, bad for battery?

Tags: battery-life

Is it bad for battery to use the option to stay awake while charging? Will it make my battery drain faster in the future?

PD: I use my phone for app development. I have activated the stay awake option to avoid unlocking the phone constantly.

Comment: It will make the phone run hotter, and heat is the number 1 enemy of your battery. It will cause further degredation of the device, but how much I have no idea as there are way too many variables.

Comment: Stay awake while charging only mean that your device's screen will not timeout when you don't touch it. You can still lock it manually.

Comment: Yes that is true, I'm just working off the assumption that it will be on for longer than just using it, i.e. the longer it is on the hotter it gets, the more risk of screen burn on an AMOLED and overheating / battery heating. :)

Answer (score 1):

As long as the battery stays below 140 deg F, the extra heat won't damage it.  See retailers' [instructions](http://www.maxamps.com/lipo-care.php), manufacturer's [data sheets](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/2750/LP552035_350MAH_3.7V_20150906.pdf), or any professional drone pilot. If anything, the battery works better at somewhat above room temperature.

Answer (score 1):

It will slightly shorten the lifespan of the battery because the screen is on. When the screen is on it uses battery. The more the battery is used the more charge cycles it'll have to go through compared to a phone with a turned off screen.

Another concern is display burn-in. Although that might not be a problem as long as you turn off the screen when you're not gonna use it for long periods of time.