# Stay awake while charging - why not?

Tags: sleep, 7.1-nougat

I am new to Android 7.1, and I would like my phone to be always on while charging. Is there any disadvantage? Are there any system processes running only in sleep mode?

Related: 
[Stay awake while charging, bad for battery?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/61879/stay-awake-while-charging-bad-for-battery)

Comment: Activate `Developer options` ( Go to Settings->About Phone->tap on build number multiple times, and it shows a message `You have enabled Developer options` after completed) , Inside developer options, check whether Stay awake is ON or not, if ON turn off by sliding left.

Comment: @RahulGopi OP didn't ask how to achieve that, but if that has any disadvantage. I'd say OP is completely capable of enabling it :)

Comment: There are no issues with background processes, you can go ahead.

Comment: @Izzy Ok, I understood.